# xdebug 3, phpstorm configuration under docker installed with wsl 2 ubunto engine with windows 10 as host machine

Tags: php, docker, debugging, docker-compose, xdebug

I have a docker installed on wsl 2 using a program named  "micro-env",

[image]

The WSL2 fixed IP is :

> 172.23.183.202

I want to add xdebug 3 to phpstorm, the xdebug is installed in a php 7 docker container.

this is the output of the command :

```
docker inspect groomrhv2-php -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}" --format json | jq .
```

Output :

```
"NetworkSettings": {
      "Bridge": "",
      "SandboxID": "7293963ad4db7c70a3c7e4c24fb7c4e04c26cf4c2c2723a55272aeba90b8fd37",
      "HairpinMode": false,
      "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
      "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
      "Ports": {
        "443/tcp": [
          {
            "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
            "HostPort": "443"
          },
          {
            "HostIp": "::",
            "HostPort": "443"
          }
        ],
        "80/tcp": [
          {
            "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
            "HostPort": "8080"
          },
          {
            "HostIp": "::",
            "HostPort": "8080"
          }
        ],
        "9000/tcp": null
      },
      "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7293963ad4db",
      "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
      "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
      "EndpointID": "",
      "Gateway": "",
      "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
      "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
      "IPAddress": "",
      "IPPrefixLen": 0,
      "IPv6Gateway": "",
      "MacAddress": "",
      "Networks": {
        "groomrhv2_dockerized_default": {
          "IPAMConfig": null,
          "Links": null,
          "Aliases": [
            "groomrhv2-php",
            "groomrhv2-php",
            "c1aa5080ef3e"
          ],
          "NetworkID": "3fb9d9c63780fe121610305d6d164d70508c1ebb3c7de9267ddbba3feff39b58",
          "EndpointID": "e717eecc4374e4f025bf83b98945d87bd8e973ebd7a53d11538fa10bb460f064",
          "Gateway": "172.22.0.1",
          "IPAddress": "172.22.0.5",
          "IPPrefixLen": 16,
          "IPv6Gateway": "",
          "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
          "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
          "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:05",
          "DriverOpts": null
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and then inside the container :

```
docker exec -ti groomrhv2-php bash
```

The output of php --ini inside container :

```
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-config.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-intl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

the xdebug extension is in : /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so

and the php.ini is in : /usr/local/etc/php

In phpstorm i added docker :

[image]

and then i added the php cli interpreter like this :

[image]

this is my xdebug.ini config :

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug,develop,profile
xdebug.discover_client_host=false
xdebug.client_host=172.23.183.202
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.idekey=GroomRHV2
XDEBUG_SESSION=GroomRHV2
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.log_level=3
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
```

and then i tried to validate debugger conf on web server :

[image]

and this is what i finally get :

[image]

I'm not currenly enable to use xdebug 3 with phpstorm, i will be grateful if someone could help me  !
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the same problem was solved by adding an option to the **.env** file (docker-compose must have), or you can fix xdebug.ini, if there accessible

```
    XDEBUG_CONFIG='client_host=172.28.80.1 client_port=9003 start_with_request=yes idekey=PHPSTORM discover_client_host=0'
```

**172.28.80.1 - my localhost pc IP** (PhpStorm working here)

[image]

the reason turned out to be that the PHP was knocking not on my Windows computer where the IDE was installed (172.28.80.1),
but on the IP of the WSL virtual machine (10.5.0.1)
and important to set **discover_client_host=0**, because we don't need auto open socket by xDebug with failed 10.5.0.1:9003 connection.

You can also insert the xdebug_info() function at the top of your starting index.php file and see where xdebug is actually trying to access:

```
<?php

xdebug_info();
die;
```

[image]

And you can watch what ports are open on your localhost
**netstat -na | find "9003"**
[image]

Localhost IP mast be pingable from your php container with index.php, check it by **ping**, or check with **telnet**

The last, optional point, without which xDebug will already work, but will not show what line the debugger stopped on, is to indicate to the storm your local server and the location of the files on the real disk and their corresponding location in the container
[image]

Comment: After a lot of pain, I found out that this is the solution : use Windows's IP address.
Additionlly, I use `start_with_request=trigger` to avoid errors when PhpStorm is not listening.